# Url-encode all ampersands found in a 1d array of strings

Tags: php, arrays, string, replace

I would like to do a string replacement in all items in an array. What I have is:

```
$row['c1'] = str_replace("&", "&amp;", $row['c1']);
$row['c2'] = str_replace("&", "&amp;", $row['c2']);
$row['c3'] = str_replace("&", "&amp;", $row['c3']);
$row['c4'] = str_replace("&", "&amp;", $row['c4']);   
$row['c5'] = str_replace("&", "&amp;", $row['c5']);
$row['c6'] = str_replace("&", "&amp;", $row['c6']);
$row['c7'] = str_replace("&", "&amp;", $row['c7']);   
$row['c8'] = str_replace("&", "&amp;", $row['c8']);
$row['c9'] = str_replace("&", "&amp;", $row['c9']);
$row['c10'] = str_replace("&", "&amp;", $row['c10']);
```

How can I achieve this with less code? I thought a foreach statement would  work,  e.g.:

```
$columns = array($row['c1'], $row['c2'], $row['c3'], $row['c4'], $row['c5'], $row['c6'], $row['c7'], $row['c8'], $row['c9'], $row['c10']);

foreach ( $columns as $value){
   $value   = str_replace("&", "&amp;", $value);
}
```

But it doesn't work.

Comment: Is this an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/352329)?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Just do:

```
$row = str_replace("&", "&amp;", $row);
```

**Note:** Your foreach doesn't work because you need a reference, or use the key:

```
foreach ( $columns as &$value) { // reference
   $value  = str_replace("&", "&amp;", $value);
}
unset($value); // break the reference with the last element
```

Or:

```
foreach ($columns as $key => $value){
   $columns[$key]  = str_replace("&", "&amp;", $value);
}
```

Although it is not necessary here because `str_replace` accepts and returns arrays.

Comment: you got it man ... I wasn't aware `str_replace` accepts `arrays` too

Comment: How would you use this method to replace a string in the second part of an array. ('array string 1','array string 2') this is an example row.

Answer (score 2):

You should call it by reference, otherwise `foreach` creates a duplicate copy of `$value`

`foreach ( $columns as &$value)`

Answer (score 1):

Another solution to is to use PHP [`array_walk`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk.php) like this:

```
function custom_replace( &$item, $key ) {
   $item = str_replace('22', '75', $item);
} 

// Init dummy array.
$columns = array('Cabbage22', 'Frid22ay', 'Internet', 'Place22', '22Salary', '22Stretch', 'Whale22Inn');

// Print BEFORE.
echo 'Before: ';
print_r($columns);

// Make the replacements.
array_walk($columns, 'custom_replace');

// Print AFTER.
echo 'After:';
print_r($columns);
```

Output:

```
Before: Array
(
    [0] => Cabbage22
    [1] => Frid22ay
    [2] => Internet
    [3] => Place22
    [4] => 22Salary
    [5] => 22Stretch
    [6] => Whale22Inn
)
After: Array
(
    [0] => Cabbage75
    [1] => Frid75ay
    [2] => Internet
    [3] => Place75
    [4] => 75Salary
    [5] => 75Stretch
    [6] => Whale75Inn
)
```