# Replace substring in column values of a 2d array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, replace

I'm trying to use `str_replace()` to remove the "my." out of the `value4` elements in an array of arrays.

However, `str_replace("my.", "", $myarray);` isn't changing anything.

Does `str_replace()` not work on two-dimensional arrays?

My sample data and coding attempt:

```
$array = [
    [
        'value1' => 'John Doe',
        'value2' => 'Father',
        'value3' => '',
        'value4' => 'http://www.website.my.com'
    ],
    [
        'value1' => 'Jane Doe',
        'value2' => 'Mother',
        'value3' => '',
        'value4' => 'http://www.website.my.com'
    ]
    // ...
];
$out = str_replace('.my', '', $array);
var_export($out);
```

Comment: @MarkBaker It can also be used with arrays, just not multidimensional

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `array_walk_recursive()` http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk-recursive.php to perform a replacement on every sub-element (Note: Callback is just triggered for *leafs* (non-arrays)):

```
$myArray = array(0 => "my.test", 2=> array("test" => "my.thing"));

array_walk_recursive($myArray, "removeMy");

function removeMy(&$element, $index){
   $element = str_replace("my.", "", $element);
}


print_r($myArray); // Array ( [0] => test [2] => Array ( [test] => thing ) )
```

if the replacement should only appear on `value4` keys - add that as a condition:

```
function removeMy(&$element, $index){
  if ($index === "value4"){
       $element = str_replace("my.", "", $element);
  }
}
```

Comment: This ultimately ended up working for me. Only question is how would I write that changed value back to the array? This doesn't seem to do so.

Comment: EDIT: Sorry, I typed your answer instead of copy and I missed the "&" before the $value. Thanks! So the "&" makes it write to the source array

Comment: @n1nja The `&` in front of a variable (for method input parameters) makes the variable *containing* just a reference on the original variable. Using `$element` without `&` will create a exact copy which you then can modify without changing the original array.

Answer (score 8):

No, it works on strings, or single dimension arrays.... you could use it through the callback in an array_walk_recursive though

```
array_walk_recursive(
    $myarray,
    function (&$value) {
        $value = str_replace('.my', '', $value);
    }
);
```

Comment: I'm not sure, but as I read the question he only wants to replace this on the key "value4": *out of the value4 field of these arrays*. But maybe OP has to write this clearer.

Answer (score 2):

Make it easy

```
foreach ($array as &$item)
   $item['value4'] = str_replace('my.', "", $item['value4']);
```

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @splash58, there is no need for a recursive approach for your 2d array.

You can most directly access and mutate the specific column value using a `foreach()`.  Declaring `&$v` in the loop signature ensures that any changes to that value are represented in the original array.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/TeDEN))

```
foreach ($array as ['value4' => &$v]) {
    $v = str_replace("my.", "", $v);
}
var_export($array);
```

---

Of course the same can be done with whole rows, but your sample data indicates that only one column is meaningfully targeted.  Anyhow, here is how you can use `str_replace()` to modify 1d arrays in the same fashion: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/N9WNv))

```
foreach ($array as &$row) {
    $row = str_replace("my.", "", $row);
}
var_export($array);
```