# Replace Array with Numbers and text

Tags: php, arrays, str-replace

My code is a simple code but i not seing what the problem might be.

I'm doing a "for" to get a number from 1 to 2000, then replacing the number into text, example '1px','2px',...

Then i set this "'1px','2px',..." in a array.
For that reason i could verify where in the text has "px" , then i could repalce it with "%". PS: "%" is also an array.

To replace the text, i use str_replace, and it funcional, but not when i use it with my code.

```
$search = array('150px','151px','152px','153px','154px',...);
$replace = array('100%');
$testes = str_replace($search, $replace, $GetText)
```

Example of $GetText - `<p><img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBOC" data-filename="andy-brown_4.png" style="width: 150px;"><br></p>`

this codes work

Now the code that im trying,

```
for($i = 1; $i<=2000; $i++) {
  echo "'". $i . 'px' . "'," ;
  $test = "'". $i . 'px' . "'," ;
}
```

Show all the number from 1 until 2000 with text, example: '274px',
[image]

```
$search = array($test);
$replace = array('100%');
$testes = str_replace($search, $replace, $GetText)
```

With this process, it doesnt replace the "px" with "%"

[image]

Comment: you're missing a comma `array('100%);` <- not sure if in your actual code or not so won't edit^^

Comment: @treyBake Its a single quote thats missing :)

Comment: My bad , i wrote the code by hand.

Comment: @RiggsFolly I prefer the single quote concat route, nicer to read IMO :p find I can lose variables inside double quotes, even with an IDE xD

Comment: post code as code, not as an image

Comment: $test will be 2000px and you will replace only 2000px with 100%

Comment: So `echo "'". $i . 'px' . "'," ;` could be `echo "'$ipx'," ;`

Comment: the code is on top, i dont have more code

Comment: Possible duplicate of [replace string in an array with php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4977048/replace-string-in-an-array-with-php)

Comment: RiggsFolly i get that it the same thing but it not replace with the str_replace

Comment: no it equal all the number for 1 until 2000

Comment: @MichaelLuis - No it won't since you're **_overwriting_** the value of the variable on every iteration.

Comment: what type of output you want. i can't understand your question

Comment: instead of showing my image with pixel it shows with 100%

Comment: @MichaelLuis `var_dump($search1);` and you will see that there is only one element, you need to push every element

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can solve your task with one php function `preg_replace`

```
$GetText = '<p><img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBOC" data-filename="andy-brown_4.png" style="width: 150px;"><br></p>';

$result = preg_replace("/\d{1,4}px/","100%",$GetText);

var_dump($result);
```

What `\d{1,4}px` mean is:
`\d` - search for digit,
`{1,4}` - previous element (e.g. digit) must be repeated from 1 to 4 times,
`px` - must be folowed by this text,

So it looks for everything like `*px` and replace it with `100%`, where `*` is any number from `0` to `9999`;

Comment: The output of $result give me Null

Comment: This is tested code. @MichaelLuis are you tryed it 1to1 with my code or change something? What php version did you have?

Comment: php version 7.2

Comment: I did it like this and it worked: $result= preg_replace("([0-9]+px)", "100%", $GetText);

Comment: Glad that you figure it out how to use regular expressions for your task. Thanks for update.

Answer (score 1):

If you want an array out of this loop, then build an array and not a string.

Incidentally doing `$test = "'". $i . 'px' . "'," ;` will overwrite the `$test` variable each time round the loop, which means you would have ended up with a single value in that string i.e. `$test = '2000px'`

```
for($i = 1; $i<=2000; $i++) {
    echo "'". $i . 'px' . "'," ;
    //$test = "'". $i . 'px' . "'," ;
    $test[] = "{$i}px";
}
```

or if you prefer

```
for($i = 1; $i<=2000; $i++) {
    $test[] = $i . 'px';
}
```

Comment: The echos may be the same but the array it builds is NOT

Comment: In your code do a `echo $test;` and you will see JUST `2000px`

Comment: me too, i just set that echo to see what i would give me

Comment: ADD a line after your loop to do `echo $test;` you will see only `2000px`

Comment: BUT YOUR ECHO and the line that sets the value of `$test` do not do the same thing

Answer (score 0):

As you can see [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php)    str_replace accepts array "This function returns a string or an array with all occurrences of search in subject replaced with the given replace value." , but i think in you case you can use [preg_replace](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php)

```
$search = []; // define search array
$GetText = '<p><img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBOC" data-filename="andy-brown_4.png" style="width: 150px;"><br></p>';//dummy text
for($i = 1; $i<=2000; $i++) {
   $search[] =  " ". $i . 'px' ; // this will push new element into the array
}  

$testes = str_replace($search, ' 100%', $GetText); // this will change every element from $search array to ' 100%'
var_dump($testes); // returns <p><img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBOC" data-filename="andy-brown_4.png" style="width: 100%;"><br></p>

var_dump(preg_replace('/(\d+)px/i','100%',$GetText));// this will give you the same result
```

Comment: @RiggsFolly this is the mistery with str_replace try this str_replace(["50px", "150px"], ' 100%', $GetText); it will return "width: 1 100%;" ... etc

Comment: @RiggsFolly i really don't like that str_replace with 2k elements

Comment: Me neither, but without a really good idea about what the OP is really trying to do it is difficult/dangerous to make other suggestions :)

Answer (score 0):

Your want an array, but handle a string here:

```
$test = "'".$i.'px'."',";
```

This code always rewrite `$test` string, so `$test` always equal to `'2000px',`.

But you need to fill an array like this:

```
$test[] =  $i.'px';
```

Be aware that you don't need a quotes here, because str_replace will be looking for quotes in text (I believe in most cases it will not find them).

The next thing that you need to go from 2000 to 1, from greater to lesser, because `str_replace` will replace first finded occurence.

In case you have `210px`, str_replace will find `10px` and replace it with your `100%` and you got `2100%`.

So, working code could looks like this:

```
$GetText = '<p><img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBOC" data-filename="andy-brown_4.png" style="width: 150px;"><br></p>';

$search = array();

for($i = 2000; $i>=1; $i--) {
    $search[] = $i . 'px';
}

$replace = '100%';

$result = str_replace($search, $replace, $GetText);

var_dump($result);
```

Hope that was what you looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You can do easily with str_ireplace

```
search = array($test);
$replace = array('100%');
$testes = str_ireplace($search, $replace, $GetText);
```